# Getting schedule posts for WPBakery's Post Grid

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I am using `WPBakery` to build a page with several posts in columns using the `Post Grid element`, narrowing the data source by List of ID's. But I'd like to get schedule posts, in order to have the page built in advance, but it can't get those. 
[WPBakery element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR8qt.png)

Does anyone had the same issue and got any workaround? I just needed the field to save the ID, even if it doesn't find the post.

Or creating a new element, maybe?